# Embedding my website's videos in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, video, embed

Is there a way I can make the videos on my website embedabble in Facebook the same way Youtube's videos are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube uses a iframe that is sized to fit the video player. Theoretically, you could do the same with your own video content.

`<iframe width="X" height="Y" 
src="http://www.example.com/yourvideocontent" 
frameborder="0"></iframe>`

Where X is width and Y is height. You might have to play with it to get it to work they way you want it to work, but this is the basic idea.